# Is it possible to run Unity 7 on 12.10 (or maybe 12.04)?

Tags: 12.10, unity

I saw a question regarding a backport from 12.10 unity to 12.04; but I would be more interested in checking out Unity 7 on my current 12.10 installation.

(updating my system to 13.04, 13.10 is unfortunately not an option - so far, our company is not allowing us to use these versions of ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Below are the steps to run Unity 7 (Next) on Ubunut 12.10

```
mkdir ~/unity
sudo apt-get install bzr
bzr branch lp:unity/phablet ~/unity/unity-next
cd ~/unity/unity-next
./build -s
./build
~/unity/unity_build/libexec/unity-people-daemon
cd ~/unity/unity-next
./run
```

If all of the steps above have completed correctly you should have Unity 7 running on Ubuntu 12.10.

<sup>Source:[Run Unity Next on Ubuntu 12.10](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-run-unity-next-on-your-desktop)</sup>

Comment: Your answer shows me that my question wasn't specific enough. You explained how to get there ( I guess by fetching the latest source code and building it); now I am wondering: ok, i am able to run it, but will it actually work "good enough"? Meaning: could I make unity 7 the default; or would that lead to random crashes and all kinds of strange problems?

Comment: I don't think that it would give you any problem, but it might since nothing is a 100%.  I would recommend testing in a VM just to be on the safe side.